# How do I show that the degree $n$ Taylor polynomials of $f$ about two points are equal?

Tags: analysis

**Question**
Suppose that $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, and that $n \ge d$. Let $x_0 \neq x_1$. Show that the degree $n$ Taylor polynomials of $f$ about $x_0$ and $x_1$ are equal.

**Attempt**
Let the polynomial be $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{d}a_kx^k$. Then the Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $x_0$ is $$P_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k}{k!}$$

and the Taylor polynomial of $f$ about $x_1$ is $$Q_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(x_1)(x-x_1)^k}{k!}.$$

For them to be equal, I think it would have to be the case that $P_n(x) - Q_n(x)= 0$

I tried with a simple example. Let $d=1$ and $n=3$. Then

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{1}a_kx^k = a_0 + a_1x ,$$

$$P_3(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{3} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(x_0)(x-x_0)^k}{k!} = a_0 + a_1(x-x_0) ,$$

$$Q_3(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{3} \dfrac{f^{(k)}(x_1)(x-x_1)^k}{k!} = a_0 + a_1(x-x_1) .$$

However, $P_n(x) - Q_n(x)= 0 \Rightarrow x_0 = x_1$ or $a_1 = 0$. Where did I go wrong?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $k=0$ term in $P_3(x)$ should be $f(x_0)$, which is $a_0+a_1x_0$, not $a_0$. Similar remarks apply to $Q_3(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

The degree $n$ Taylor polynomial of a polynomial of degree $\le n$ is simply that polynomial itself - no matter what point you develop at. If you don't believe it, observe that the Taylor error term is a multiple of some $f^{({n+1})}(\xi)$, hence zero.